# Commutation relations following from quantization of a complex scalar field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, commutator, second-quantization, klein-gordon-equation

As someone who has recently started doing QFT I have some (algebraic) confusion about the following derivation.

Starting with the Lagrangian of a complex scalar field $$\mathcal{L} =\partial_\mu \psi^* \partial^\mu \psi - m^2 \psi^* \psi ,$$ with the conjugate momenta to $\psi$ and $\psi^*$ being $\pi = \dot{\psi^*}$ and $\pi^* = \dot{\psi}$. It is possible to write the complex field operators as
\begin{equation}
\hat{\psi}(\textbf{x}) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}} (\hat{b}_p e^{i \textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}} + \hat{c}_p^\dagger e^{-i \textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}}) 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\hat{\pi}(\textbf{x}) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} (-i) \sqrt{\frac{\omega_p}{2}} (\hat{b}_p^\dagger e^{-i \textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}} - \hat{c}_p e^{i \textbf{p} \cdot \textbf{x}}). 
\end{equation}
The commutation relations for these complex field operators are
\begin{equation}
[\hat{\psi}(\textbf{x}),\hat{\pi}(\textbf{y})] = i \delta^{(3)} (\textbf{x} - \textbf{y})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
[\hat{\psi}(\textbf{x}),\hat{\pi}^\dagger(\textbf{y})] = 0.
\end{equation}
So far so good, but then my lecture notes say that these commutation relations imply that
\begin{equation}
[\hat{b}_p, \hat{b}_q^\dagger] = (2 \pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\textbf{p} - \textbf{q})
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
[\hat{c}_p, \hat{c}_q^\dagger] = (2 \pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\textbf{p} - \textbf{q}),
\end{equation}
with all other relations being 0. It is not very obvious to me how these would follow the commutation relations for the complex field operators.
This is how far I got working out the first relation, omitting the hats on operators:
\begin{equation}
[\hat{\psi}(\textbf{x}),\hat{\pi}(\textbf{y})] = -i \int \frac{d^3 p d^3 p'}{2 (2 \pi)^6} \sqrt{\frac{\omega_{p'}}{\omega_p}} ([b_p,b_{p'}^\dagger] e^{i(\textbf{p x - p' y})} + [c_{p'}, c_p^\dagger] e^{-i(\textbf{p x - p' y})} + C) + i \int \frac{d^3 q d^3 q'}{2 (2 \pi)^6} \sqrt{\frac{\omega_{q'}}{\omega_q}} ([b_q,b_{q'}^\dagger] e^{i(\textbf{q x - q' y})} - [c_{q'}, c_q^\dagger] e^{-i(\textbf{q x - q' y})} + B).
\end{equation}
In writing this out I have thrown away all terms with double creation/annihilation operators and normal ordered the ones with one creation/annihilation operator such that $b_p b_{p'}^\dagger = B + b_{p'}^\dagger b_p $, and similar for the $c$ operators. How would one go on to show that the commutation relations for $b, c$ actually hold? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Next step
\begin{equation}
= -i \int \frac{d^3 p}{2 (2 \pi)^3} (e^{i p (\textbf{x - y})} + e^{-i p (\textbf{x - y})} + C) + i \int \frac{d^3 q}{2 (2 \pi)^3} (e^{i q(\textbf{x - y})} -  e^{-i q(\textbf{x - y})} + B).
\end{equation}

Comment: I think there is a sign problem in the exponentials for $\pi$. These should be interchanged.

Comment: @Jon Yes you are right, I updated it, also changed the signs in my calculation

Comment: Ok, now you can apply the commutation relations and see that the $\delta$ makes $q=q'$ and you are left with $\delta^3({\bf x}-{\bf y})$.

Comment: @Jon Tried applying them, wrote my result in the edit, it's still a bit confusing. Do we assume the commutation relations for $b, c$ and $b^\dagger, c^\dagger$ to be true in this step? Also why is it required that $q=q'$ and not some other arbitrary number?

Comment: No, you are integrating $q'$ away and no $\delta$ is left. Yes, you are assuming the commutation relations between $b$s and $c$s to hold. You are left with the integral definition of the $\delta$ that is what one should have.

Comment: @Jon Ah yes I get it now, thanks for the help